# Dynamically change the type of a class attribute

Tags: c++

I'm coding a class that has a vector as a private attribute.
The type of the vector ( it can be a concurrent_vector from the TBB library or a std vector) is only known at runtime, depending on a parameter specified by the user.

So the question is, how can I code that? I thought something like:

```
class A {
  private:
     void* vec;
  public:
    A( int type ) {
       if ( type == 1 ) {
         // convert the void* into std::vector<>
      } else {
         // convert into a tbb::concurrent_vector
      }
  }
};
```

That conversion, could it be done by a reinterpret_cast? Or is there another better way to do this?

I'm in blank.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a fixed set of types, a [`boost::variant<>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/variant.html) may be a suitable solution.

```
boost::variant< tbb::concurrent_vector<int>, std::vector<int> > member;
```

It has the benefit that it's fast (it does not use `new`, but stores the vectors in place), and tracks the type for you. If the set of possible types isn't fixed, you can use [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/any.html)

```
boost::any member;
```

But then you need to track the type stored yourself.